# Django Rest Framework - The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I had a React Axios post working with textfields, but now I'm trying to add an image field to my model.

Here is my new model with the image field:

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('posts', str(instance.author), filename)


class TripReport(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=False, related_name='trip_countries')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, null=True, blank=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=12, unique=True, blank=True)
    favoriters = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favoriters')
```

I'm pulling the file off of my form with this:

```
e.target.image.files[0]
```

which logs a file object like this:

```
{ name: "DSCF6638.JPG", lastModified: 1340012616000, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 5395895, type: "image/jpeg" }
```

when I console log it.

I've added the image variable to my POST request in axios:

```
export const postTripReport = (author, title, content, countries, image) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(postTripReportsPending());
    axios.post(
      'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/reports/',
      {
        title: title,
        content: content,
        author: author,
        countries: countries,
        image: image
      },
      {headers: { 'Authorization': `Token ${token}`}}
    )
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(postTripReportsFulfilled(response.data));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(postTripReportsRejected());
        dispatch({type: "ADD_ERROR", error: err});
      })
  }
}
```

I'm new to this, so I'm not sure how the form is currently encoded. It's just a simple input:

```
   <input
      name='image'
      accept="image/*"
      id="flat-button-file"
      multiple={false}
      type="file"
    />
```

I've tried adding the multipart/forms-data headers to the axios request, but then it said that no file was uploaded and that all of the other fields were blank. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instead of JSON? `const formData = new FormData(); formData.append('image', image); ... ; axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/reports/', formData);`

Comment: Can I do that for just the image, or should I append all of the fields to formData?

Comment: All the fields you currently have in the JSON should be put in the `formData` instead, so you get `axios.post(url, formData, { headers });`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put your data in a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object instead of using a regular object. This way axios will send the data as `multipart/form-data` instead of as JSON.

```js
const formData = FormData();

formData.append("title", title);
formData.append("content", content);
formData.append("author", author);
formData.append("countries", countries);
formData.append("image", image);

axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/reports/", formData, {
  headers: { Authorization: `Token ${token}` }
});
```

Comment: I was struggling with this for almost an hour. The fix is correct. One thing I noticed is, don't add ", {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    }" to the code after making the data in formData. It won't work!! Thank you